# Обособление "как у первоклассника"

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

> Сидит он... Ручки(,) как у первоклассника(,) сложены!

Мне кажется, здесь и в запятых можно, и без! Если акцент на "сложены", то нужны две запятые! Если же акцент на "как у первоклассника", то запятые не нужны!!! Я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ изменен.

Действительно, здесь возможны оба варианта, но нужно правильно расставить ударение при чтении:

(1) *РУчки, **как у первоклАссника**, слОжены!*

(2) *Ручки **как у первоклАссника** сложены!*

Но при другой структуре предложения оборот может не обособляться (только одно решение): *Слушает меня **внимАтельно,** ручки как у первоклассника **слОжены.***

Здесь акцент делается на перечислении действий (предложение бессоюзное сложное).